# Merging two mySQL queries with a join

Tags: mysql

I know I need to do some sub-query for this, but I can't get it to work.

Query 1:

```
SELECT full_db3.dma, dma_list.dma_name 
from `full_db3` 
inner join dma_list on full_db3.dma = dma_list.dma;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT dma, COUNT(*) as dma_count, 
    round(COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM full_db3) * 100,2) as dma_percent 
FROM full_db3 
where dma != '0' 
GROUP BY dma 
ORDER BY dma_count DESC;
```

The first query matches a dma number to a dma name. What I need is for this dma name to be added into what's returned from the query as a result of query 2 to give me: `dma, dma_name, dma_percent`

What's the best way to combine these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `JOIN` with `dma_list` to the second query:

```
SELECT full_db3.dma, dma_list.dma_name, COUNT(*) as dma_count, 
    round(COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM full_db3) * 100,2) as dma_percent 
FROM full_db3 
INNER JOIN dma_list on full_db3.dma = dma_list.dma
where full_db3.dma != '0' 
GROUP BY full_db3.dma 
ORDER BY dma_count DESC;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks. I'll accept the answer when I'm allowed.